# traceroute: findsaddr: write: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, freebsd, traceroute

I have a FreeBSD machine with traceroute Version 1.4a12+FreeBSD. When I try to run traceroute, I get the following error. However the same command works fine on my Mac.

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute: findsaddr: write: Invalid argument
$
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I tried posting to superuser.com, but got no responses. So trying on stackoverflow.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out? If yes then it may be good to add an answer of your own.

Comment: No, I haven't found it yet.